# Relationship queries

Tags: apex, relationships, code

I have started learning relationship queries. I have created a new field in case, contacts and opportunities which are related to accounts.I want to update that new field with account's type field.
I wrote a program but I can't get the result. Please tell me, whats wrong with my program and how to update that field.

My Program:

---

```
public class TestClass {
    public void updateChildrec(){
        List<Account> allAcc = [Select Id, Name,Type,
                                (Select Name,Account_Type__c from Account.Contacts),
                                (Select Name,Account_Type__c from Account.Opportunities),
                                (Select CaseNumber,Account_Type__c from Account.Cases)
                                 From Account ];
            for (Account acc : allAcc)
        {
            for (Contact con : acc.Contacts)
            {
                con.Account_Type__c = acc.Type;
                         }

            for (Case cases : acc.Cases)
            {
                cases.Account_Type__c = acc.Type;

            }
            for (Opportunity oppty : acc.Opportunities)
            {
                oppty.Account_Type__c = acc.Type;
            }

        }

        update allAcc;
    }

}
```

---

Comment: If you're not explicitly trying to practice with relationship queries, then I'd suggest making use of a _formula field_ on each of your child objects to pull in data from the parent record. No queries or code to worry about (and less prone to errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SOQL looks fine in terms of accessing the child records but I suggest you consider filters as these are shared standard objects across your instance.

It looks as if the database operations is where you are not seeing expected results.

Unfortunately, you will have to build a collection of each child object to be updated.

```
public class TestClass {
    public void updateChildrec() {
        List<Account> allAcc = [
            Select Id,
                Name,
                Type,
                (Select Name, Account_Type__c from Account.Contacts),
                (Select Name, Account_Type__c from Account.Opportunities),
                (Select CaseNumber, Account_Type__c from Account.Cases)
            From Account];

        List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>():
        List<Opportunity> opportunities = new List<Opportunity>():
        List<Case> cases = new List<Case>():

        for (Account acc : allAcc) {
            for (Contact con : acc.Contacts) {
                con.Account_Type__c = acc.Type;
                contacts.add(con);
            }
            for (Case casess : acc.Cases) {
                casess.Account_Type__c = acc.Type;
                cases.add(casess);
            }
            for (Opportunity oppty : acc.Opportunities) {
                oppty.Account_Type__c = acc.Type;
                opportunities.add(oppty);
            }
        }
        update contacts;
        update opportunities;
        update cases;
    }
}
```

Please consider limits such as DML statements & returned rows in these transactions. Child queries and dmls will count against your overall transaction allowance.

Comment: Thanks Smith.Its working.

Comment: Parent-Child subqueries are counted against a different governor limit (the poorly named "aggregate queries" limit) which has a higher threshold (300) than regular queries. The `allAcc` query thus consumes 1 SOQL query and 3 "Aggregate" queries.

Comment: Hi Derek, Can we write up to 300 aggregate queries in one query?

Comment: @Richie No, I think the limit is 20 or 25 per query. The 300 number is the limit for all queries executed in a given transaction.

Comment: @Derek  Can you tell me how to calculate query rows in this transaction.

Comment: @Richie That's getting into "new question" territory, but it's highly dependent on both your data and the filters in your `WHERE` clauses. Such a question would be hard to answer accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Using Apex here can work, but it's not the right tool for the job.

Instead, you should use a *formula field* on each of your child objects to pull information down from the parent record.

Each of the objects you're using already has a relationship to the `Account` object (the `AccountId` field), so your custom relationship field may not be required at all. For sake of example though, let's assume that it is required, and the field name in each case is `Account__c`.

The formula would simply be `Account__r.Type`.
That's really all there is to it.

`Account__r` traverses up the relationship hierarchy to get you access to the Account fields (in queries, apex, formulas, etc... we change "__c" to "__r" to get data from a related (parent) record).

There is a limit on how many "object references" you can have across all the formula fields on a given SObject (which last I recall was 10), and it's a pain to try to count those references, but if you're not running into that limit I'd strongly advise using a formula field instead of Apex.